# googles recaptcha(version 2) response

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, recaptcha

How do you handle the JSON response from google?

This is how I get the JSON:

```
 res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            //process.stdout.write(chunk);//formats it like I need it

            var lines =JSON.parse(chunk);
});
```

What I get from google(e.g.), how the google JSON looks like:

```
{ success: false, 'error-codes': [ 'missing-input-response' ] }
```

What I thought would work:

```
JSON.parse("{ success: false, 'error-codes': [ 'missing-input-response' ] }").success;
```

Of course it does not work, because it is not proper formated.

What actually works(but for that I need to transform the JSON from google):

```
JSON.parse("{  "success": false,  "error-codes": [    "missing-input-response"  ]}").success
```

Then I found [this](https://github.com/aldipower/nodejs-recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha.js):

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {//chunk is the JSON from google
    var lines = chunk.split("\n");
    if(lines.length >= 2) {
        if(lines[0] == 'true')
            that._recaptcha_response.is_valid = true;
        that._recaptcha_response.error = lines[1];
    }
    that.emit('data', that._recaptcha_response);
  });
});
```

But this does not seem to work on my place, maybe they changed the JSON from recaptcha version 1 to version 2 ?!.

**UPDATED**

A deeper look showed the following:

[Look here](http://s30.postimg.org/v9via0p4h/stackoverflow.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON may already have been parsed for you. `{ success: false, 'error-codes': [ 'missing-input-response' ] }` is how Node.js prints out the object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solved my problem:

```
JSON.parse(blal.replace(/\n|\r/g, "")).success;
```

Assuming `blal` is googles JSON.